# ASP.NET Identity - Do I need to dispose ApplicationDbContext manually in controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, dispose

I have my own controller, where I am making private instance of ApplicationDbContext. Question is, do I need to write Dispose method in every custom controller, like for regular DbContext, or ApplicationDbContext has some base class to inherit Dispose method?

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Carousels()
    {
        IList<Carousel> list = db.Carousels.ToList();
        if (list.Count() == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Carousels = "0";
            return View();
        }
        ViewBag.Carousels = "1";
        return View(list);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

I'm using ApplicationDbContext, generated from asp.net Identity, where I've added custom classes, so I need the instance of ApplicationDbContext to call a lists of my objects. In case where I have my own DbContext, beside ApplicationDbContext, I usually make BaseController class, where I override Dispose method, so I don't need to write this in every controller. 
The problem is that I do not know how the identity works behind the scene completely. Is there anywhere else done override of Dispose method inside of Identity, or I can use base controller that will contain override Dispose method same as when I am using any other DbContext inside controller?
Base question I guess will be...Does ApplicationDbContext of Identity have any differences from any DbContext, because inherits from IdentityDbContext not DbContext

Comment: No, Typically dispose methods are used to free up un-managed memory. When your controller goes out of context and there arent anymore references to it, the garbage collector will take care of it for you

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I don't like to wait garbage collector, so when I am using my own DbContext, I always override Dispose method in BaseController. I don't know should I do the same with ApplicationDbContext

Comment: If your DbContext is injected through the constructor by the registered IoC then the framework will dispose the controller dependencies when the controller instance is cleared.

Comment: @mr.Panzerman How did you instantiate ApplicationDbContext? Could you show the code?

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: Sorry guys, my question was not clear. I hope you will understand now what I am asking...I added code, and explanation

Comment: @gh9 - That is dangerous advice. While the GC will take care of it for you, it will do it on its own time. In a situation where there is a very low load on the system, that could be upwards of 30 minutes. In the mean time, it is possible that all your connection threads become occupied as a result of leaking them by waiting for the GC to take over, which will cause multiple issues to occur, mostly that anything touching the Db will throw an exception.

Comment: What I've seen mostly people override dispose in their controller, typically if the application size is big and chances of all pools gets occupied is more